# Custom Field is Not Editable When Multiple Values are selected

Tags: cpq, quote, qcp

We are facing one weird issue on Quote Line Editor, we have multiselect picklist with picklist values as (Sales & marketing,HR,Finance and Custom) where, if we select **Custom** (Picklist Value) then we are enabling (we are making **Custom Planning LOB** as editable field) **Custom Planning LOB** text box. This works fine when we select **Custom** as a picklist value 
[image]

However if we are selecting **Custom** along with other values like following , then the **Custom Planning LOB** is going readonly.
We tried with QCP code to make this field editable using following piece of code

```
if (line.Planning_Lob__c && line.SBQQ__ProductCode__c && line.Planning_Lob__c.includes('Custom') && 
        fieldName === 'Custom_Planning_LOB__c' && line.SBQQ__ProductCode__c === 'PLAN-300' ) {
        return true
}
```

but its not giving the expected result.
Please suggest and advise.

[image]